# How to add a string to some URLs

Tags: php

I have a php file that generates an xml feed containing a list of all the products of my e-commerce.

For each of the products, the php file is designed to assign a series of tags (price, title, description etc...). One of these tags is the link of the product on my e-commerce.

Example:

```
<title> smartphone </title>

<category> electronics </category>

<price> 100 </price>

<link> www.mysite.com/smartphone </link>
```

This is the part of the code (working) used to extract the link of the product (my e-commerce is made with prestashop):

```
$link = $item->addChild('LINK', $productobj->getLink();
```

The thing that I need to do, is to dynamically add some string at the end of the link generated for each product.

For example, if the link is:

> [www.mysite.com/product-name](http://www.mysite.com/product-name)

I need the link to be like this:

> [www.mysite.com/product-name?parameter1=abc&parameter2=def&parameter3=ghi](http://www.mysite.com/product-name?parameter1=abc&parameter2=def&parameter3=ghi)

And the parameters need to be adapted based on the value of the tag `<category>`.

Example:
if the product A has the tag `<category>electronics</category>`

the string to add at the end of its url would be:

> ?parameter1=electronics&parameter2=def&parameter3=ghi

if the product B has the tag `<category>clothes</category>`

the string to add at the end of its url would be:

> ?parameter1=clothes&parameter2=def&parameter3=ghi

Thanks in advance for your precious help.
Good evening.

EDIT:
I report below more detail of the code used to generate the xml file.

```
<?php

public function addChildWithCDATA($name, $value = NULL) {
        $new_child = $this->addChild($name);
        if ($new_child !== NULL) {
            $node = dom_import_simplexml($new_child);
            $no   = $node->ownerDocument;
            $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($value));
        }
        
        return $new_child;
    }

}


require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php');

    $config = Configuration::getMultiple(array('PS_LANG_DEFAULT', 'PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT'));
        
    $defaultLangId = $config['PS_LANG_DEFAULT'];
    $defaultCountryId = $config['PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT'];

    Context::getContext()->language = new Language($defaultLangId);
    Context::getContext()->link = new Link();

$products = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($query);  

    $counter = 0;
    if ($products) {

        $itemlist = new SimpleXMLElementExtended('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ITEMLIST></ITEMLIST>');


        foreach ($products as $product) {

            $item = $itemlist->addChild('ITEM');

            
            $productobj = new Product($product['id_product'], false, $defaultLangId);
            
            $counter++;
            $item->addAttribute('ID', $productobj->id);

$item->addAttribute('CITYID', $defcityID);
            $item->addAttribute('CATEGORYID', $product['CATEGORYID']);

$title = $item->addChildWithCDATA('TITLE',trim($productobj->name));
            $title = $item->addChildWithCDATA('TEXT',strip_tags($productobj->description));
            $email = $item->addChild('EMAIL', $defemail);
            $link = $item->addChild('LINK', $productobj->getLink());

}
        
        unset($products);

        $success &= file_put_contents(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/feed.xml', $itemlist->asXML());
        echo "DONE";
    } else {
        echo "NOTHING FOUND";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? We can't really help you unless we know how you are parsing the data from the XML file

Comment: Cant you use something like: $link = $link.'?parameter1='.$parameter1.'&parameter2='.$parameter2.'&parameter3='.$parameter3; ??

Comment: Your link should be as friendly as possible and point directly to the product without parameters. Let htaccess do the work for you! Here's an example link from a competitor: https : // www . samsung . com / uk / smartphones / galaxy - note 20/ - SEO is very important. I would reconsider your approach.

Comment: Hello, @freefall I have added more details about the code in my post. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add the category as a URL parameter, you could use:

```php
$link = $item->addChild('LINK', $productobj->getLink() . "?parameter1=" . $product['CATEGORYID']);
```

Comment: Thank you @freefall , problem solved! In the end, I have decided to add just one parameter: ?parameter1=value1 because the category ID was not added using your code. It works only if I add a "static" parameter.